# What is the best way to check if internet connection is alive?

Tags: linux

I am student and I connect to internet with [Shibboleth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth_%28Internet2%29).
Actualy I have a Python script on a raspberry pi with selenium and phantomjs to automatically connect on running.

I would like to check internet connection without flooding the network.

Icinga monitoring, netstat established connections, ping, nmap ...
Best way?

Comment: There is rarely a best way, but usually a way that works best for you.  To help you choose you should add as much detail in your question as possible including all the requirements (how you want to be notified, do you need a dashboard, what you've tried already, etc.)

Comment: What are your criteria to determine what's best?

Comment: So if 8.8.8.8 is reachable and 8.8.4.4. isn't is that indicative of a active Internet connection?

Comment: Yes it is but isn't that way flooding my residence router ?

Answer (score 3):

It would be incorrect to assume that a connection has to be either dead or alive and that you can reliably tell the difference. This kind of assumption leads to unreliable systems because you may end up relying on a heuristic that doesn't actually check the aliveness property you expected it to.

A better approach is to monitor whether the thing you need to connection to do for you is actually working. For instance if you need a specific client to connect to a specific server, then that is what you should monitor for. As long as the two keep communicating, you don't care whether a different heuristic would consider the connection to be down.

If the monitoring does detect a problem, then you might want the monitoring to alert on that. It might be you want the monitoring to not only detect the connection being down and alert, but also try to correct the problem. This however leads to more questions.

For example assume you have hardware which could power cycle a network component in case of an outage. Then maybe you don't want to power cycle it just because the client and server cannot communicate with each other. It could be that the other end of the connection was down, and the power cycle was not needed. It may even be that power cycling would introduce an outage of its own or get in way of manual intervention.

There are ways around such issues. For example if the connection to the server appears to be down, then you could send out a DNS lookup for the server. If you got a reply, then it wasn't because the connection is completely down. But you don't even have to send the request all the way to the DNS server. You could send out the DNS lookup with a low hop limit. For example if you send a DNS lookup with a hop limit of 3 and got an ICMP back from the third hop, then it is unlikely that power cycling the 1st hop would solve the problem.

This of course is not a silver bullet. Even the best heuristics will sometimes go wrong. If you would ever build something trying to automatically restart a broken connection, you certainly need to ensure that it has an exponential back-off strategy to stop it from repeatedly restarting.

Monitoring connectivity obviously cannot be done without exchanging any packets. But you do want to limit the cost of processing those packets. For example though you can send a packet out a few hops and get an error message back from a specific router, that is not the cheapest operation for most routers. If you can find a way to send a packet out and back without involving anything but the hardware forwarding part of the routers, then that is cheaper, even if it takes more hops to do so.

If you have more sites, you can improve the reliability of the connection monitoring by having them periodically communicate with each other pairwise. If one site simultaneously lost connectivity with all other sites, then it is very likely that this one site has a connectivity problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to know if internet access is possible, a DNS lookup of www.google.com via the servers at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 is the most reliable way.

If you can't get an answer then there most certainly is something wrong with your internet connectivity. Note that "something wrong" doesn't mean no access at all.

You can't prove an internet connection is perfect.

Comment: There could be a peering issue between you and google.  So it isn't necessarily something wrong with your internet, but I would think pinging 8.8.8.8 would be sufficient, I don't see the need for a DNS lookup.

Comment: ICMP is more likely to be dropped than UDP or TCP

Comment: By a router maybe, but an end host shouldn't be dropping ICMP randomly.

Comment: When trying to check an internet connection routers are likely to be involved.

Comment: That isn't how it works.  Routers will still forward the ICMP packets, they just won't reliably reply back.  A server (such as 8.8.8.8) should reliably reply back.   If you ping, you aren't looking for a reply back from the routers, if you traceroute, you are.

Comment: All packets are equal, but some packets are more equal than others. But if you want to believe routers don't treat IP packets differently based upon their protocol field I'm not going to argue with you.